# JSP Session issue with response.sendRedirect() or with request.getRequestDispatcher()

Tags: jsp, session, redirect

I'm using a web app with this structure:

```
main/index.jsp
main/first/index.jsp
main/second/index.jsp
```

In my main/index.jsp I've got a login form, witch enable a session variable and a redirect, depending on what kind of user/pass I'm putting in. Actually I'm using request.getRequestDispatcher("/first/index.jsp") and request.getRequestDispatcher("/second/index.jsp") to redirect from the login page. The 2 webapps (first and second) are enabled only if their session variable is enabled, and both of them have some variable passed through link like this:

```
main/first/index.jsp?id=1&var=2
```

My current problem is: when i pass from main/index.jsp to one of the other 2 webapps, my url don't change. It should be main/second/index.jsp but it's still main/index.jsp, and all my links in that page are messed up (because they are relative to their folder), so if i try to use my links that passes variable through link I won't obtain this:

```
main/second/index.jsp?id=2&var=1
```

but this:

```
main/index.jsp?id=2&var=1
```

I've tried to solve this putting, on the links, their home path, but after one "iteration", the second one will have a correct url, so the second one will be something like this:

```
main/second/second/index.jsp?id=3&var=1
```

still something useless and wrong.

I've tried using response.sendRedirect() instead of using request.getRequestDispatcher() but with this solution I am losing the session variables: after the redirect, everything is lost.

Can someone help me please? Thank you.

Comment: Have you investigated what the difference is between sendRedirect() and getRequestDispatcher() is?  Here is a good starting point: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181

Comment: will you please tell me your jsp and servlet file code so i will resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this after some tests. I needed to use full address when I was passing variable through URL like this:

```
<a href="/main/first/index.jsp?id=1"> One, 1</a>
```

instead of using this:

```
<a href="index.jsp?id=1"> One, 1</a>
```